# Create shortcut key in firefox to open a URL

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, xubuntu

My system is Xubuntu 16.04 and I would like to create a shortcut key to open a URL. I don't want a desktop entry to open a URL, I know that I can create a desktop shortcut to open a URL. To be precise: Is it possible to set a shortcut key combination to open a URL directly in firefox (not a desktop entry!)?
thanks, Vladi

Comment: Are you asking for a shortcut key within Firefox (i.e. open Firefox, press keys, Firefox goes to website), or are you asking for a system wide shortcut key that opens a specific URL in Firefox (i.e. press keys, Firefox opens, Firefox goes to website)?

Comment: @3D1T0R yes it is the first option: shortcut key WITHIN Firefox (open Firefox, press keys, Firefox goes to website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly in firefox, but isn't using a desktop shortcut either. It won't create a file or link anywhere visibly in your files, so I assume this will fit your needs:

1. Go to settings and open your `Keyboard` settings
2. Go to the `Application Shortcuts` tab
   [image: settings]
3. Hit `Add` and enter the following command: `firefox --new-tab "http://example.com"` The `--new-tab` is important if you don't want firefox to open a new window.
4. Hit `Ok` and enter the shortcut you would like to use for this URL.

That's the closest you can get to having a shortcut without a desktop launcher or something like that. There might be an addon for firefox but with bare firefox I don't think it's possible to have an URL shortcut, except for your homepage, of course. (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>)

Comment: This creates a system wide shortcut, not a shortcut *within* Firefox, as requested by OP.

Comment: OP asked to not have a desktop entry, which my answer won't create. There is no option to do it all just in firefox without external add-ons.

Comment: In the title, and in a comment OP specifies that they want a shortcut *within* Firefox. While this may work for OP, it's not what was requested. If Firefox doesn't have this functionality built in, I see no indication that OP isn't willing to use an extension/add-on, so that should be the recommendation.

Comment: Well, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys/ would be a solution. Let's wait for OP to clearify which option they'd prefer.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in my cursory search, but I didn't like the way it was implemented. Also... @confetti: Just to be clear, I'm not saying this answer should be taken down or anything, just pointing out that it's not what OP asked for, and thus another answer should be given that is more in line with the request. (If I have time, I might do it.)

Comment: You might be right, but the way OP worded the question sounds to me that the reason he wants it to be *within* firefox is that he doesn't want a visible shortcut on his desktop. Personally, I would prefer this global shortcut over the add-on too since the add-on's permission would kinda bother me.

Comment: OK! It doesn't work as expected, I have firefox open then I type the shortcut as explained by @confetti then firefox opens again as a second window loading the URL . Sorry but I don't want this behavior. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: I'm sorry but what does it mean "OP"??

Comment: @confetti I tried this addon (shorkeys) BUT unfortunately it doesn't work for me,I can't set any combination keys, I don't know why. I'm running Firefox Quantum 61.0.2(64bit)

Comment: I have edited my answer, please try again with the updated command.

Comment: @confetti THAT'S IT! it works perfectly, thanks. Can I ask the command to open a URL in the same tab?

Comment: There's sadly no support yet to open an URL in the current tab.